# How do I write an if statement to display certain filters and text on a web page using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display certain text and apply a filter on one specific page of a wordpress site. I am using the code below, but it is not working. Specifically, it doesn't look like the if statement is properly capturing the web page and passing the resulting code through. Any tips for how to fix this?

The page in the wordpress site that I want to apply this code on is called "Predicting Renewals". It is currently listed as private, not public. I want to make that clear just in case that is part of the problem.

```
<?php
    global $user_select_name;
    global $_POST;
?>

<?php if ($_POST == 'Predicting Renewals') { ?>
    <script>
        $('#current-view').html('<center><h4 style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px;"><?php echo $user_select_name ?> Chapter</h4></center> <hr>');
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `$_POST` is global anyway. and it is an array, but not a variable, so you need the value of a specific `POST` parameter, like `$_POST['type'] == 'Predicting Renewals'`.

Comment: Can you try `var_dump($_POST)` and see if you find the string `"Predicting Renewals"` anywhere? `$_POST` is an array so your if condition might never match to true

Comment: Also  $_POST may not be set at all. Are you even sure that there is a POST request?
You really should do `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` at least.

Comment: The global WP post object is accessed via `global $post` … And that is a complex object, it is not equal to a string value. You need to access the specific _property_ of the post object that you want to compare to here (title, slug, …)

Comment: @mitkosoft I may have been wrong to call $_POST in the first place. If my goal is to be able to apply the "if" statement code on a specific page on the wordpress site, is there a method to do that you recommend?

Comment: @MattLefkowitz check out my answer. This should do what you want.

Comment: @MattLefkowitz, it depends what do you understand by `specific page`. If you are talking about the page itself, then the answer provided by @disinfor would be enough. If you want to capture specific `$_POST` parameter somewhere in your site, then you have to play with `$_POST` array itself.

Comment: @mitkosoft  I am talking about the page itself. There are 5 total pages on the whole site. I just added this page and I'm trying to apply different rules on it than there is on the other pages. I tried the code below (thank you @disinfor). Unfortunately it did not work for me.

Comment: @mitkosoft would it be better (or possible) if I did the "if" statement on the url itself to be more specific?

Comment: @MattLefkowitz post a comment on the answer, not here. What didn't work for you? What is the `slug` of your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check `is_page()` using the slug or page ID.

```
<?php global $user_select_name; ?>

<?php if (is_page('predicting-renewals') ) { ?>
    <script>
        $('#current-view').html('<center><h4 style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px;"><?php echo $user_select_name ?> Chapter</h4></center> <hr>');
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Documentation for `is_page()`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

If this is not a page, but a normal post, you can use `is_single()` and pass the same slug or id.

Comment: I went into the WordPress site and changed some settings with the template and the code worked. Thank you for all your help!